# How to sort integer array in ascending and descending order using lambda only in java

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8, java-stream

```
int[] arr2 = new int[] {54, 432, 53, 21, 43};
```

I am using this to sort but it is giving an error.

```
Arrays.sort(arr2, (a, b) -> a - b);
```

This is also giving an error.

```
arr2.sort((a, b) -> a - b);
```

Comment: Never use a comparator like `(a,b)->a-b` for `int` values. It may work in some use cases, but the difference between two `int` values may be bigger than the `int` value range and cause overflows. Therefore, use `(a,b) -> Integer.compare(a, b)` resp. `Integer::compare`. To reverse the order, use `(a,b) -> Integer.compare(b, a)`. Do not negate the value returned by a compare function, that will fail if the value is `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: "giving error" **what** error? Please specify this information.

Comment: @IanKemp in this case, it’s obvious enough. Arrays don’t have a `sort` method and the `sort​(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)` method does not support primitive type arrays.

Comment: @Holger Whether it's obvious enough is irrelevant - the rules specify that a question must include a **specific** problem or error. "Giving error" is the same as saying "doesn't work", which is not helpful to anyone - especially not people who might be looking for the specific error caused by using a comparator like `(a,b)->a-b` with `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: @Holger Thank you for continuing the battle to eradicate subtraction as a means to compare two int values.

Comment: @Holger why does this work:
    int[][] array = new int[][]{{5,7}, {4,9}, {6,8}, {2,5}};
    Arrays.sort(array, (a, b) -> a[0] - b[0]);

Comment: @cwa in Java, a two dimensional array is an array of arrays. Since an array is an object, a two dimensional array is therefore also an array of objects. In other words, when you have `int[][] array`, then, `array instanceof Object[]` will also be `true`. So, `int[][]` being an array of objects, you can use the generic method `sort​(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`. But read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126952/?noredirect=1#comment95086199_54126952) again, using minus as comparator works for some (small) values but is broken in general and will lead to hard-to-track bugs

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could sort the input of type `Integer[]` as :

```
Integer[] arr2 = new Integer[] {54,432,53,21,43};
Arrays.sort(arr2, Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

or possibly with primitive types as :

```
int[] arr2 = new int[]{54, 432, 53, 21, 43};
int[] sortedArray = Arrays.stream(arr2)
        .boxed()
        .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()) // just use 'sorted()' for ascending order
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .toArray();
```

or further using a trick from one of the existing answers (do note that it should be cautiously used with boundary values though) :

```
int[] sortedArray = Arrays.stream(arr2)
        .map(i -> -i).sorted().map(i -> -i) // just use 'sorted()' for ascending order
// Edit - use map(i -> ~i).sorted().map(i -> ~i) to be safe from the issue with Integer.MIN_VALUE
        .toArray();
```

***Edit***: For an in-place ascending order sort, you just need to perform :

```
int[] arr2 = new int[]{54, 432, 53, 21, 43};
Arrays.sort(arr2);
```

Comment: For ascending order, you can use `Arrays.stream(arr2).sorted().toArray()` or just sort in-place with `Arrays.sort(arr2)`. However, be aware that the trick with negating the values does not work if one or more occurrences of `Integer.MIN_VALUE` are among the values.

Comment: @Holger true, that's what I meant in the note before the `map.sort.map` solution about boundary values.

Comment: As explained in [Stuart Marks’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54139536/2711488), using binary not (`~`) instead of minus (`-`) would solve the issue with `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for sharing. Would spend some time reading Stuart's answer later for sure.

Answer (score 12):

Given

```
int[] array = ... ;
```

To sort ascending, simply do

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Here's a pretty way to sort descending:

```
Arrays.setAll(array, i -> ~array[i]);
Arrays.sort(array);
Arrays.setAll(array, i -> ~array[i]);
```

This is a tiny bit slower than sorting ascending and then reversing the array; it has to do an extra pass over the array. The runtime is dominated by the sorting for an array of any significant size, so it's unlikely to be noticeable.

This works by doing a bitwise complement of the int values before and after the sort. This provides an exact, lossless reversal of the ordering of every possible int value. To see this, you have to understand that Java ints use [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation. Consider if ints were to have only three bits. All the values would be as follows:

```
         100  101  110  111  000  001  010  011
          -4   -3   -2   -1   0    1    2    3
MIN_VALUE ^
```

The bitwise complement operator `~` inverts every bit. You can see by inspection that this reflects the table about a pivot point between -1 and 0, so -4 becomes 3, -3 becomes 2, etc. Also, another complement will restore the original value. Thus, an ascending sort on the complemented values is a descending sort on the original values.

Note that this differs from negation `-` which doesn't do the right thing here. It reflects the table **at** zero, so the negation of zero is zero, the negation of -1 is 1, etc. This is asymmetric, because the negation of MIN_VALUE is MIN_VALUE. Thus, using negation in an attempt to perform a descending sort doesn't work.

Finally, boxing and using a Comparator works, but it's considerably slower, and it allocates a separate object for (almost) every int value. I recommend avoiding boxing.

Comment: Hi! Wouldn't the fact that you need to do all this work with the bits mean that a new method is needed? i.e. Arrays.sortDescending

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Quite possibly. It might be useful to add some primitive array operations. This does seem to be a frequently asked question, and common answers (such as those that involve boxing) perform quite poorly.

Answer (score 7):

**Sort in ascending order :**

1. ```
   int[] ascArr = Arrays.stream(arr2).boxed().sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder())
                                     .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
   ```
2. ```
   int[] ascArr = IntStream.of(arr2).boxed().sorted((a, b) -> Integer.compare(a, b))
                                    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
   ```
3. `int[] ascArr = Arrays.stream(arr2).sorted().toArray();`

---

**Sort in descending order :**

1. ```
   int[] descArr = Arrays.stream(arr2).boxed().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                                      .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
   ```
2. ```
   int[] descArr = IntStream.of(arr2).boxed().sorted((a, b) -> Integer.compare(b, a))
                                     .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
   ```

Answer (score 4):

There are different ways to create a sorted array of `int`s out of an unsorted one using streams, as the other answers show. These approaches have the disadvantage of either requiring boxing/unboxing (so that a `Comparator<Integer>` can be used), or that new arrays are needed to accommodate the elements.

Here's a way to sort in-place without boxing/unboxing. First, in ascending order:

```
int[] arr2 = ...
Arrays.sort(arr2);
```

Unfortunately, there's no way to sort in-place in descending order using a single-line operation. You will need to sort ascending first, then reverse the array:

```
int[] arr2 = ...
Arrays.sort(arr2);

int size = arr2.length;
for (int left = 0; left < size / 2; left++) {
    int right = size - i - 1;
    int temp = arr2[right];
    arr2[right] = arr2[left];
    arr2[left] = temp;
}
```

---

**EDIT:** As @Holger points out in the comments, the `for` loop above could be improved as follows:

```
for (int left = 0, right = arr2.length - 1; left < right; left++, right--) {
    int temp = arr2[right];
    arr2[right] = arr2[left];
    arr2[left] = temp;
}
```

---

An alternative is to sort in ascending order and then place the elements in reverse order into a new array:

```
int[] arr2 = ...
Arrays.sort(arr2);

int size = arr2.length;
int[] reversed = new int[size];
Arrays.setAll(reversed, i -> arr2[size - i - 1]);
```

This uses [`Arrays.setAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll(int%5B%5D,java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator)) to accomplish the task.

Comment: You may consider a simpler `for(int left = 0, right = arr2.length-1; left < right; left++, right--) …` which may also be more efficient in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class lambdaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr2 = new int[] {54,432,53,21,43};

        int[] sorted = IntStream.of(arr2)
                .boxed()
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .mapToInt(i -> i)
                .toArray();
        System.out.println("In decending Order:");
        for(int ss : sorted)
        {
            System.out.print(ss+", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        int[] reversed = IntStream.range(0, sorted.length)
                .map(i -> sorted[sorted.length-i-1])
                .toArray();
        System.out.println("In Ascending Order: ");

        for(int ss1 : reversed)
        {
            System.out.print(ss1+", ");
        }
    }

}
```

> **OUTPUT**
>
> **In decending Order:**
>
> 432, 54, 53, 43, 21,
>
> **In Ascending Order:**
>
> 21, 43, 53, 54, 432,

**Edit:** much simpler to sort in natural order `(IntStream.of(arr2) .sorted() .toArray())`

**Thanks to [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger)**

Comment: It would be much simpler to sort in natural order (`IntStream.of(arr2) .sorted() .toArray()`) and reverse that, to get both, instead of sorting in reverse order and reverse that again.

Comment: Yeah, i got it, but i presented other way of doing it :?, hope it is ok??

Comment: Sure, but there’s an advantage in the approach of reversing the array, as together with a straight-forward ascending order sort, you can do it without any boxing overhead. That advantage gets lost when doing the first sort with boxed values (as unavoidable when using a `Comparator`).

Answer (score 2):

If you explicitly need a custom comparator lambda, try this one:

```
    int[] arr2 = new int[] {54,432,53,21,43};
    int[] arr3 = IntStream.of(arr2).boxed().sorted((a, b) -> a - b).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```